# Are hardware ports within the same namespace as software ports?

Tags: windows, port

If we have soft port 80 for http,which can be connected by `telnet localhost 80`,

can there be an I/O(hardware) port with the same number 80?

Comment: What do you want to connect to the COM port?

Comment: @harper, I'm just trying to understand the relationship between hard/soft ports actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http is **TCP** port 80

It has nothing to do with hardware vs software (and yes, there exist hardware implementations of TCP/IP networking).

TCP port numbers have meaning when they appear in a TCP packet header.  There is no connection to other types of port numbers, e.g. I/O port numbers which are used by the [`inb` and `outb` functions](http://linux.die.net/man/2/inb) and (on x86 computers) appear on the address lines of the system bus (e.g. ISA or PCI).  If you called `inb(80)`, it would not mean "http" in any way.  On my computer, I/O port 80 (0x50) is used by the system timer.

---

Note: The windows equivalent to `inb` is [`READ_PORT_UCHAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560797.aspx).